# Command line command order

Tags: windows, command-prompt

Today I wanted to get a list of files in a particular directory. The easiest way to accomplish this is to open a prompt and run a

```
dir > filelist.txt
```

I assumed that first the 'dir' command runs and then its output is created. It is THEN redirected to the file.

What is interesting however is that the directory listing inside of 'filelist.txt' includes 'fielist.txt' with zero bytes which was not expected.

Once the command completes 'filelist.txt' actually shows as having 450 bytes (when I run a dir without the redirection, same prompt).

1) Why does 'filelist'txt' show up at all?

2) What is the command prompt doing behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0):

> I assumed that first the 'dir' command runs and then its output is created.

Where would the output live in the meantime?

The output is by default displayed on the console, almost immediately after being output by the program.

Now if you redirect the output to a file instead, it is written to that file as it would be written to the console: at the moment the program writes the output.

Even when a command has no output, the file is still created. The console first tries to create the requested output file; if that fails, the requested command won't even be executed.

Comment: I am assuming that there is some buffer in the background where each command runs, its output is buffered (which in this case would NOT include the next input) and then passed to the next input. Kind of like a sink or middleware.